# Pass entered value from one table to another table using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to pass the entered value to table two when user I click add, the quantity will be added to the second table. When I click Add button quantity is displayed as an empty value. But not console this shows the entered quantity
The `quantity` is of the same name and the `quantityEntered` is of the same name. When I inspect element I get the value entered on the...

```
"quantityEntered": <input type="text" id="CLT-K809S/SEE_quantity" name="quantityEntered" class="form-control" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)"  readonly=readonly value="1" />
```

...on every row of my new table.

Here is my code:

```
function saveEneteredQuantity() {

    var quantity;
    var quantityName;
    var getEnteredQuantity;
    var enteredQuatity;
    var getIndex;
    var textvalue = "";

    quantity = document.getElementsByName("quantity").length;
    quantityName = document.getElementsByName('quantity').value;
    console.log("Count the lenght of the input textbox on the HO Stock : ", quantity);
    document.getElementsByName("quantityEntered").value = quantityName;
    getEnteredQuantity = quantity;
    for (var i = 0; i < quantity; i++) {
        textvalue = textvalue + document.getElementsByName("quantity").item(i).value;
    }
    $('[name="quantity"]').each(function(index) {
        getIndex = $(this).val();
        enteredQuatity = $('[name="quantity"]').eq(index).val();
    });
    quantity = textvalue;
    alert("This was provided: ", quantity);

    debugger;
    console.log("Check the grapped quantity on table of Selected Line Items to Order : ", quantity);
    if (quantity == '' || quantity == 0) {
        alert("Quantity can not 0.\n Please enter quantity which is less than available quantity");
    }
    console.log("Entered Quantity: ", quantity);
}

var items = [{
    "avalaibleQty": '<input type="text" id="CLT-C659S/SEE_avaliableQuantity" name="avaliableQuantity" class="form-control" readonly="readonly" value="1">',
    "quantityEntered": '<input type="text" id="quantityEntered" name="quantityEntered" readonly="readonly" class="form-control" />',
    "quantity": '<input type="text" id="quantity" name="quantity" class="form-control" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" onblur="compareQuantity(this, 1)" required="required" value="" />',

}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix the problem I had by creating hidden input which I use to store my entered quantity and when user clicks add button,which is on the first and create my second table. I than get crap the entered value assign it to my hidden input.

`<!-- part Number and Quantity Entered -->
<input type="hidden"id="quantityList" name="quantityList" class="form-control" value="" />`

```
    var quantityList = [];  

    $(".addLineItem").on("click", function() {

       debugger;
       var items = [];
       var row = $(this).closest("tr").clone(); 

       var partNumber = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(0)').find('input').val();
       var quantity = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(4)').find('input').val();

       quantityList [quantityList.length]= [quantity];

       document.getElementById("quantityList").value = quantityList;

       debugger;
       items.push(row);
       row.appendTo($("#mySecondTable"));
   });
```